# Compiler won't pass values of constructor

Tags: java, constructor

hi i am new to java and trying to learn the basics , i have been going around with the constructor methods and faced a problem

```
public class Employee {
int emp_id;
String name;
String Depart;
double Salary;
double bonus;
boolean resident;

public Employee() {
    emp_id = 1;
    name = "null";
    Depart = "General";
    Salary = 0.0;
    bonus = 0.0;
    resident = true;
}

public Employee(int x , String y) {
    x = emp_id;
    y = name;
}

public Employee(int x , String y , boolean b) { 
    this (x,y);
    b = resident;
}

public void print_emp() {
    System.out.println("Employee name = "+ name +"\nHis ID is : " + emp_id + "\nHis department is : "+ Depart + "\nResidency = " + resident + "\nHis salary = "+Salary);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Employee e1 = new Employee(20,"Ali");

    e1.set_dept("Auto");
    e1.print_emp();
}
```

}

When I try to print it just gives me default constructor values which are :

```
Employee name = null
His ID is : 0
His department is : null
Residency = false
His salary = 0.0
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: `set_dept` is not defined. Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Assignment is from left to right

```
emp_id = x;
name = y;
```

Comment: wow thanks man it worked , but why does it make a difference ?

Comment: otherwise you're just assigning null values to your local variables `x` & `y`

Comment: @MohamedGamalHamed As a general practice, try making all method parameters `final`. It would prevent this bug.

Answer (score 0):

In these two constructors, you have your assignment operations backwards:

> ```
> public Employee(int x , String y) {
>     x = emp_id;
>     y = name;
> }
> public Employee(int x , String y , boolean b) { 
>     this (x,y);
>     b = resident;
> }
> ```

Assignment is from left to right, so these should be written like this instead:

```
public Employee(int x , String y) {
    emp_id = x;
    name = y;
}
public Employee(int x , String y , boolean b) { 
    this (x,y);
    resident = b;
}
```